# Get pointed elements with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to get the pointed item with jquery.I mean by pointed item, if the mouse click on some div in the body, i want to get that div's info , or click on a select box or etc.. so they are no tchoasen by me, the selected items are all html elements in the web, just i want to recieve the info of the element witch i have been clicked on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document.body).click(function(ev) {
    $(ev.target); // is the clicked element
});
```

[Live Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Raynos/AwcsQ/3/)

[`ev.target`](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) [`.click`](http://api.jquery.com/click/)

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/

http://api.jquery.com/event.currentTarget/

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I am not sure if I understand your question but are you are refering to `.html()` method. The examples below will pop up the div's content upon click or hover.

**Example**

```
<div id='test'>Content of div</div>

//on click
$('#.test').click(function(){
    alert($(this).html());
});

//on hover
$('#.test').hover(function(){
    alert($(this).html());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have a `div` having id 'test' inside your `body` element. Register event by jQuery as:

```
$("div#test").click(function(event){
    alert(event.target); 
    /*here event is the object fired, and target is the Div element i.e. source or you can use 'this' to refer to Div element*/
     alert(this);
     // Here 'event.target' and 'this' will give the same Div element.
});
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew, actually I didn't know how to use code window, new to stackoverflow